# Flink read data from hdfs

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

I'm a freshman in Flink and I am wondering that how to read data from hdfs . Can anybody give some advices or some easy examples for me ? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your files are formatted in text file format, you can use 'readTextFile' method from 'ExecutionEnvironment' object.

Here is an example of various data sources. (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/batch/index.html#data-sources)

Comment: Thank you very much , and I have deal with this after I asked this quesition . And , I have another quesition : such as these API(TextInputFormat or FileInputFOrmat) ,what is the meaning of these , and how to use them . Do you konw that ? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Flink can read HDFS data which can be in any of the formats like text,Json,avro such as.
Support for Hadoop input/output formats is part of the flink-java maven modules which are required when writing flink jobs.

Sample 1 : To read text file named JsonSeries and print on console

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<String> lines = env.readTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/input/JsonSeries.txt")
        .name("HDFS File read");
lines.print();
```

Sample 2 : using input format

```
DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> inputHadoop =
        env.createInput(HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(new TextInputFormat(),
                LongWritable.class, Text.class, "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hadoop/input/JsonSeries.txt"));
inputHadoop.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flink 1.13, Hadoop 3.1.2, Java 1.8.0 on the Centos7 machine I was able to read from HDFS.
`HADOOP_HOME` and `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` were exported already. I think from version 1.11 something changed. I couldn't find even a simple example. Therefore I share my example.

I added to `pom.xml` following dependency

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

My Scala code:

```
package com.vbo.datastreamapi

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
object ReadWriteHDFS extends App {
  
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment


  val stream = env.readTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/train/datasets/Advertising.csv")

  stream.print()

  env.execute("Read Write HDFS")

}
```